# Is the .NET Framework free software?

Tags: .net

Is the .NET Framework free software, or not? It seems that the .NET Framework is freely available, so I want to create a program that requires the user to install the .NET Framework in order to use it.
Are there any licensing issues that I should be worried about in choosing to do so?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing questions are explicitly disallowed on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6):

Free as in beer - yes, it costs nothing to install or download the .NET framework

Free as in speech - no, it is closed source, proprietary code.

It is gratis, not libre.

Comment: Free as in beer is a statement that always makes me laugh. What I want to know is where to find this free beer!

Comment: I have a can you can have if you can make it to my flat :D

Comment: @David - http://freebeer.org - But that is free beer as in speech.

Comment: However, the source *has* been released for reference purposes. So, it's not quite your daddy's closed source.

Comment: There is also Mono. And .NET has a standard.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, .net is free in the sense that you can distribute programs built against .net without paying any licensing money to Microsoft.

Comment: +1: You can also create .Net programs for free by using the Express editions of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Everybody can install the .NET Framework without having to pay any fees to Microsoft. Also, you can develop applications with the .NET Framework and you don't have to pay fees, either. Neither do you have to pay fees when you release your applications.

Answer (score 0):

windows system contains .net framework, e.g. windows 7. but if you want to install the development tools: visual studio, Sql server... then you need to pay for them.

Answer (score 0):

Seven years later: Not all of it, but most of .NET has been released under the terms of the MIT license, and is available at https://github.com/dotnet . It officially supports "Linux, Windows, and macOS" (the order of that list is Microsoft's, at https://www.microsoft.com/net )

It was always freely distributable in binary form (for Windows), and linkable from your own software without restrictions (on Windows), otherwise nobody would have wanted to use it and Microsoft wouldn't have gained the users they wanted.